# How do I launch multiple windows in WPF?

Tags: wpf, user-controls

Simple question but surprisingly I couldn't find any answer in MSDN or did I miss some links ?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want to do is open a window this is quite simple, just instantiate a new instance of a window from code and then call `.Show()` on the instance:

```
var newWindow = new NewWindow();
newWindow.Show();
```

You can then host UserControls within that window.

I don't think you can open a user control without hosting it in a window, though I'll do some tinkering to confirm that belief now.